# before @ symbol only value fetch not after value query in myaql in php

Tags: mysql

I would like to run a query that returns the part before @ symbol  not after value @ . For example :- field name `jabber_id` has a database value of `iloho_user_88@107.180.100.93` so i fetch only this value "`iloho_user_88`"  not after @ symbol.How to fetch this query? (So this jabber_id is increment  iloho_user_88 ,iloho_user_880, iloho_user_100, particular user id is increment) Please help for me Thanks.

Comment: what you tried so far ? and show the code

Comment: This question will never close. No point in trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring

> Returns the substring from string str before count occurrences of the delimiter delim. If count is positive, everything to the left of
>   the final delimiter (counting from the left) is returned. If count is
>   negative, everything to the right of the final delimiter (counting
>   from the right) is returned. SUBSTRING_INDEX() performs a
>   case-sensitive match when searching for delim.

```
mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('www.mysql.com', '.', 2);
        -> 'www.mysql'
mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('www.mysql.com', '.', -2);
        -> 'mysql.com'
```

In your case you have to use @